# Use of Directline Enhanced authentication in a uwp client

Tags: uwp, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm working to a custom uwp Directline client for a bot and I'm using client authentication. The bot server works in the emulator and authenticate the user.
I implement the flow in the uwp and i open the uri passed in oauthcard in a webview and at the end of the flow I'm redirected to a page that ask to enter a magic code instead close the authentication flow. I think that the issue is in the domain list in the directline configuration page but not sure how to handle it as the client is not hosted in a web server in a specific domain

Comment: When you say domain list, are you talking about the trusted origins on the direct line page?  How is the bot hosted? Have you tried the domain for that?  for example https://{your site}.azurewebsites.com?  The way you described it it should like the bot is hosted on the client somehow.  I'm not too familiar with UWP so I'm trying to understand the issue better.

Comment: uwp is a native application in Windows 10 so it's not hosted. I'm developing a multi channel conversational application that in the case of the uwp application it offer a richer esperience for kiosks

Comment: Yes i try to add the server domain in the trusted origin. The scenario could be similar to what appen for emulator but in that case seems it use a special code to do that

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now out of the box.  You might be able to add a proxy between your client and the Direct Line connector services, but this would be complex for sure.